# A [Song from Taylor Swift's second album] Puzzle

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle

<sub>This puzzle is part of the [Monthly Topic Challenge #14: Think inside the (very small) box!](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7497/monthly-topic-challenge-14-think-inside-the-very-small-box).</sub>

---

Can you solve the following clues, fit their answers into the grid below, and then determine what belongs in the 16th cell (obscured by the question mark)?

[image: a 4x4 grid, with columns colored alternatively red and off-white, except for the bottom right cell, which is black with a white question mark]

> American slang term for the police
> Broadway musical in which Ariana Grande made her debut
> Chelsea F.C.'s most recent kit sponsor
> Figure often seen tied in knots
> It features two Elizabeths, for the time being
> It's represented by a red flag with a white cross
> More of these means something is finer
> Nickname for the third group of astronauts selected by NASA
> River in North Yorkshire
> She got her name from a mark on her arm
> Something many association football and ice hockey goalkeepers choose to wear
> Song from Taylor Swift's second album
> Taking the Browns to the Super Bowl is doing this?
> This is often given up high
> Three of these together is a bad sign

Comment: Does the order of the clues matter?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All of the clue answers are

> numbers, from 1 to 15

Specifically,

> - Something many association football and ice hockey goalkeepers choose to wear = 1, [as their jersey number](https://soccerfolders.com/why-do-goalkeepers-wear-number-1/)
> - Taking the Browns to the Super Bowl is doing this? = Defecating, aka "going #2"
> - Chelsea F.C.'s most recent kit sponsor = [Three](https://www.chelseafc.com/en/three)
> - It's represented by a red flag with a white cross = [4](https://flagdom.com/nautical-flags/code-flags)
> - This is often given up high = [5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_five)
> - Three of these together is a bad sign = [6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_of_the_beast)
> - River in North Yorkshire = [7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/River_Seven)
> - Figure often seen tied in knots = 8
> - More of these means something is finer = [9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nines_(notation))
> - It features two Elizabeths, for the time being = [£10](https://www.bankofengland.co.uk/banknotes/polymer-10-pound-note), with pictures of Queen Elizabeth II (deceased, but it seems that the Bank of England hasn't gotten around to issuing new notes with King Charles III) and Jane Austen character Elizabeth Bennet.
> - She got her name from a mark on her arm = [Eleven](https://www.timesnownews.com/viral/why-stranger-things-fans-are-being-warned-not-to-get-eleven-tattoo-article-92076663) (*Stranger Things* character)
> - American slang term for the police = [12](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-12-slang-for-police-in-America)
> - Broadway musical in which Ariana Grande made her debut = [13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/13_(musical))
> - Nickname for the third group of astronauts selected by NASA = [14](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NASA_Astronaut_Group_3)
> - Song from Taylor Swift's second album = [15](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fifteen_(song))

The 16th cell should be

> empty

because according to your question title,

> the grid is a [15 Puzzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/15_puzzle), and needs one unoccupied position so that tiles can be slid around.

Comment: BTW, how do you do list markup inside spoiler markup?

Comment: I don't believe bullets work in spoilers, but I've separated your answers onto different lines so they're a bit easier to read. hopefully that helps. in the future you can do this by adding two spaces at the end of each line

Comment: nice job working your way through the answers, btw! enjoy your green check